# Match vectors in sequence

Tags: r, vector, string-matching

I have 2 vectors.

```
x=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c")
y=structure(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), .Names = c("a", "e", "b", 
"c", "d", "a", "b", "c"))
```

I would like to match `a` to `a`, `b` to `b` in sequence accordingly, so that `x[2]` matches `y[3]` rather than `y[7]`; and `x[5]` matches `y[6]` rather than `y[1]`, so on and so forth.

```
lapply(x, function(z) grep(z, names(y), fixed=T))
```

gives:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 6

[[2]]
[1] 3 7

[[3]]
[1] 4 8

[[4]]
[1] 5

[[5]]
[1] 1 6

[[6]]
[1] 3 7

[[7]]
[1] 4 8
```

which matches all instances. How do I get this sequence:

```
1 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

So that elements in `x` can be mapped to the corresponding values in `y` accordingly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are actually looking for `pmatch`

```
pmatch(x,names(y))
[1] 1 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Answer (score 6):

You can change the names attributes according to the number of times each element appeared and then subset y:

```
x2 <- paste0(x, ave(x, x, FUN=seq_along))
#[1] "a1" "b1" "c1" "d1" "a2" "b2" "c2"
names(y) <- paste0(names(y), ave(names(y), names(y), FUN=seq_along))
y[x2]
#a1 b1 c1 d1 a2 b2 c2 
# 1  3  4  5  6  7  8
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option using `Reduce`

```
Reduce(function(v, k) y[-seq_len(v)][k],
    x=x[-1L],
    init=y[x[1L]], 
    accumulate=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I did it with a for-loop

```
#Initialise the vector with length same as x.
answer <- numeric(length(x))
for (i in seq_along(x)) {
  #match the ith element of x with that of names in y.
  answer[i] <- match(x[i], names(y))
  #Replace the name of the matched element to empty string so next time you 
  #encounter it you get the next index.
  names(y)[i] <- ""
}

answer
#[1] 1 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility:

```
l <- lapply(x, grep, x = names(y), fixed = TRUE)

i <- as.integer(ave(x, x, FUN = seq_along))

mapply(`[`, l, i)
```

which gives:

> ```
> [1] 1 3 4 5 6 7 8
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Similar solution to Ronak, but it does not persist changes to y

```
yFoo<-names(y)
sapply(x,function(u){res<-match(u,yFoo);yFoo[res]<<-"foo";return(res)})
```

Result

```
#a b c d a b c 
#1 3 4 5 6 7 8
```